# Plural of A: As vs A's

Tags: apostrophe

If I want to say that I excelled all my class this summer, I might say "I got all As this summer". Is this correct vs using "A's"? I see the latter used everywhere. But with the presence of apostrophe it sounds to me like it would make it possessive and not plural.

Comment: It appears to be that case. Should I just delete this one?

Comment: Deletion's not necessary, but you should at least [accept the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/323179) since it sounds like it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I was not able to the accept duplication button in the mobile app.